# WCF test client redistribution

Tags: wcf

I am working on a product which provides WebServices and clients often need some simple client to test them. WCFTestClient Tool is really good for that purpose.

Is it legal to include WCFTestClient Tool from Visual Studio as a part of you product's installation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the [MS user terms](http://www.microsoft.com/legal/useterms.):
Search for Visual Studio (version you own), and check it's EULA (available in pdf).

EDIT: for my VS2012 Pro found this:

ADDITIONAL LICENSING REQUIREMENTS AND/OR USE RIGHTS.

...

b. Utilities. The software contains certain components that are identified in the Utilities List located at go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247624. Depending on the specific edition of the software, the number of Utility files you receive with the software may not be equal to the number of Utilities listed in the Utilities List. **You may copy and install the Utilities you receive with the software on to other third party machines. These Utilities may only be used to debug
and deploy your programs and databases you have developed with the software. You must delete all the Utilities installed onto a third party machine within the earlier of (i) when you have finished debugging or deploying your programs; or (ii) thirty (30) days after installation of the Utilities onto that machine.**

**BUT,**

there is no `WcfSvcHost`/`TestClient` in that list (`go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247624`).
I assume you can distribute both without any restrictions